# combinatorial calculation: how many are the subsets $A$ of $X$ such that $|A∩Y| = 1$?

Tags: combinatorics

I have to solve this exercise:

> how many are the subsets $A$ of $X$ such that $|A∩Y| = 1$

$$X = \{1,2,3, ..., 10\}\\Y =\{1,2,3,4\}$$
But, I don't understand why the formula is $4\cdot2^{10-4}$ and not $4\cdot(2^6-1)$, since we don't want to consider the set empty.

Comment: Is it $2^\color{red}2\cdot2^{10-4}$?

Comment: Yes, I wrote it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want $A$ to have one element from $Y$; there are $4$ possibilities for that.

As far as the six elements in $X$ that are not in $Y$,

each of them could or could not be in $A$, so there are $2^6$ possibilities there.

So altogether there are $4\times2^6$ possibilities for $A$.

(The set $A$ won't be empty, because we designed it to have an element from $Y$.)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't considering the $4$ case where $A$ has only one element.